# Can't install heroku-cli. Path is missing

Tags: heroku, path, solus

I've been trying to install heroku. When I run `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh` on terminal I get this message : `'Your path is missing /usr/local/bin, you need to add this to use this installer.'.`

I've already tried to add this to $PATH, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. When I run echo $PATH this is what I get : `'/home/rasklow/usr/local/bin:/home/rasklow/.rbenv/shims:/home/rasklow/.rbenv/bin:/home/rasklow/.rbenv/shims:/home/rasklow/.rbenv/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:**/usr/local/bin**:/snap/bin.`

Now /usr/local/bin appears to be in there, so I don't how else to install heroku. I've tried to download directly the tar.gz file but I'm fairly new to linux and I don't know how to install the package correctly.

Comment: It looks like you wrapped `/usr/local/bin/` in **. Try removing the asterisks from the path and try again. I.e. your path should end something like this: `/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin`

Comment: Another approach: since it looks like `/snap/bin` is already in your path, you may be able to use the snap based install: `sudo snap install --classic heroku`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530073/cant-install-heroku-cli-path-is-missing/53542289#comment93933539_53530073)

> Another approach: since it looks like `/snap/bin` is already in your path, you may be able to use the snap based install: `sudo snap install --classic heroku` - [davejagoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142505/davejagoda)

The snap based install worked

Comment: Good to hear. Please try to accept your own answer. Link to Heroku docs is here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

Comment: I ran into another configuration hell trying to get snap to work.  The path /usr/local/bin exists, so the error if faulty.  Searched all over - no solution to this problem, so appears Heroku is as bad as when I tried it years ago.  Back to the VPS.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this issue is to sudo to root: `sudo su -`

And then do the install: `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh`

All of the checks will pass and no changes will need to be made. After installation, exit out of root.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more like a workaround/a hack. I had the same issue on open-SUSE 15.1. When I echoed the path it showed that  `"/usr/local/bin/"` was available on the path but still installation halted.
What I did was manually adding it on the bashrc of the local user account. Basically on my .bashrc, I added this line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

So far everything still works, so I'm just leaving it there

Answer (score 0):

Another hack which worked for me (On Amazon Linux 2) was to download the install script and after verifying that `/user/local/bin` was added to the path, I commented out the check in the script (lines 20-23 in the version as of 2/8/22) and then ran the script:

Step 1: download script: `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh > ./install_heroku.sh`

Step 2: add `/usr/bin/local` to path: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/local`

Step 3: Comment out the if statement on lines 20-23 of the install script (just add `#` to the beginning of each line)

Step 4: Run `cat ./install_heroku.sh | sudo sh`